# Using lens for array indexing if both array and index are in State

Tags: arrays, haskell, haskell-lens

I have an array and an array index in a state monad. I can read idx using `use` and modify it using `+=` and other similar modifiers:

```
{-# Language TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Array

data M = M { _arr :: Array Int Int, _idx :: Int }

$(makeLenses ''M)

foo x = do
    idx += x
    ii <- use idx
    return ii
```

Now I want to combine `arr` and `idx` to form a  lens to `arr[idx]`:

```
combo arr idx = undefined

bar x = do
    combo arr idx += x
    ii <- combo arr idx
    return ii
```

How can I do this? Will code be different for `Data.Sequence`?

Comment: I don't know if there's already a suitable lens defined somewhere. Still, it seems that you can build your own lens using the `lens` function and specifying your own getter and setter.

Comment: You'd need to build your own lens for that. Or use something like `use idx >>= \idx -> fmap (!! idx) $ use arr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be just

```
combo arr idx f m = (arr . ix (m^.idx)) f m
```

As the index may be out of bounds, `ix` is a partial lens called `Traversal`. So `bar` has to use `uses` instead of `use`:

```
foo x = do
    combo arr idx += x
    ii <- uses $ combo arr idx
    return ii
```

Also `ii` is `Monoid m => m Int` instead of `Int`, because of partiality.

If original unsafe behaviour of returning `Int` is needed it can be restored by replacing `uses` with `unsafeUses traversal = (^?! traversal) <$> get`