# Array indexing lens out of array and index lenses

Tags: haskell, composition, haskell-lens, lenses

This is a simpler version of [Using lens for array indexing if both array and index are in State](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27245512/805266) as I have resolved some issues. I'm not sure if I should delete the original or edit it in place.

Given

```
{-# Language TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# Language Rank2Types #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH
import Data.Array

data M = M { _arr :: Array Int Int, _idx :: Int } deriving (Show)

$(makeLenses ''M)
```

I want to write a function

```
combine :: Lens' M (Array Int Int) -> Lens' M Int -> Lens' M Int
```

That takes `arr` and `idx` lenses and constructs a combined lens that can be used to read and write an element pointed to by `idx`. The lens I want exists:

```
comboGet :: M -> Int
comboGet m = _arr m ! _idx m

comboSet :: M -> Int -> M
comboSet m v = m { _arr = _arr m // [(_idx m, v)] }

combo1 :: Simple Lens M Int
combo1 = lens comboGet comboSet
```

I understand that `comboGet` and `comboSet` can in principle be rewritten to use solely `arr` and `idx` lenses.

My question is: what is the most idiomatic way to construct `combo1` out of `arr` and `idx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct it like this:

```
combo :: Lens' M Int -- alias for 'Functor f => (Int -> f Int) -> (M -> f M)
combo f m = arr (\xs -> fmap (\r -> xs // [(i, r)]) $ f $ xs ! i) m
  where i = m^.idx
```

### EDIT

The better `Traversal` version would look like this:

```
betterCombo :: Traversal' M Int
betterCombo f m = arr (\xs -> maybe (pure xs) 
                                    ((\r -> xs // [(i, r)]) <$> f)
                                    xs^? ix i) m
  where i = m^.idx
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
betterCombo f m = (arr . ix i) f m
  where i = m^.idx
```

Comment: Aha! `Simple Lens` is just `Lens'`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that as `!` is partial, `Lens'` is not the way to go and I should use `Traversal'` instead:

```
combine :: Lens' M (Array Int Int) -> Lens' M Int -> Traversal' M Int
```

`comboGet` and `comboSet` can be rewritten using lens combinators:

```
comboGet' :: M -> Int
comboGet' m = m ^?! almostCombo m

comboSet' :: M -> Int -> M
comboSet' m v = m & almostCombo m .~ v where

almostCombo :: M -> Traversal' M Int
almostCombo m = arr . ix (m ^. idx)
```

`combo` of @chaosmasttter can be written as:

```
combo2 :: Functor f => (Int -> f Int) -> M -> f M
combo2 f m = arr (\xs -> fmap (\r -> (ix i .~ r) xs) . f $ xs ^?! ix i) m  
    where i = m^.idx
```

It's `Traversal` signature will only differ by `Applicative`:

```
combo :: Applicative f => (Int -> f Int) -> M -> f M
```

Will `Applicative` help us make the result of getter optional?

As  @chaosmasttter pointed out in his `betterCombo`, the key was to eta-expand lens composition to get access to `m`.

Comment: Yes you can use `pure` form `Applicative` to make a real `Traversal`, see my edit to my answer.